# Running a local tinkerpop gremlin graph for testing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm looking for a solution to run a gremlin tinkerpop graph locally to use for toy graphs for unit testing with Jest. I saw tinkergraph, but it doesn't appear to have a javascript implementation that I can find. Any recommended solutions would be appreciated.

I am currently testing by querying my neptune instance, which is obviously not ideal from a speed or cost basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Gremlin Server locally.  Either as a binary [1] or use the pre-built container image [2].

[1] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/download.html

[2] https://hub.docker.com/r/tinkerpop/gremlin-server

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `testcontainers` to run integration tests in my Node app.

For the container actually running you can follow this guide to try to mimic Neptune as close as possible in your local/CI env https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automated-testing-of-amazon-neptune-data-access-with-apache-tinkerpop-gremlin/

Answer (score 0):

### Try `gremlin-air-routes-api` Kit

This project contains:

1. A gremlin server that runs locally pre-loaded with the Air-Routes Example Dataset. This requires Docker or Docker Desktop on your system.
2. Contains a basic Node.js/web page combo that uses Gremlin.js API to access the Gremlin Server via TypeScript based code.

[GitHub](https://github.com/imanabu/gremlin-air-routes-api/tree/main)

You should be able to launch the system quickly and start testing and then use that to code other Node.js project with Gremlin.

If you improve this, please send me a Pull Request.